# Dynamically loading a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to implement a *dynamically* loaded `ListView` (includes scrolling, fetching and dynamically loading content onto the screen).

One way to implement this is by using the `onScreenScrollListener()`, but is there any other efficient way of implementing this, since the `onScreen()` event is generated everytime the top list item goes *out of focus* from the screen on the top.

Comment: you can follow [this][1] link and [this][2] link here..,maybe it helps you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761639/android-dynamic-loading-list-view-onscrolllistener-issues
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398921/dynamic-listview-adding-load-more-items-at-the-end-of-scroll

Comment: Dear, your requirement `(i.e. includes scrolling, fetching and dynamically loading content onto the screen)` is already handled by ListView, by default. ListView only needs data-list (data-set) to be displayed.

Comment: sure: use a AbstractWindowedCursor and some CursorAdapter adapter

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are looking for is `pagination` for `ListView` items (loading of next page items when scrolled to some point near the end of the list)

I suggest you check out [AmazingListView](https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/), it's *not very easy to use* but it is a useful component not only providing pagination but also providing *iPhone like* `Section Header` Implementation

Answer (score 0):

Set the AbsListView.OnScrollListener on your list view or grid view and implement the methods with something like this:

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
  if (((scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_FLING) || (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)) && isShowNextPage()) {
    loadNextPage();
  }
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
  setShowNextPage(firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount > (totalItemCount - pagingTolerance));
}
```